# Teams botframework send proactive message REST api

Tags: javascript, botframework, microsoft-teams, rest, proactive

I Try to create new converation and send proactive message with teams bot (botfreamwork).

I used this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=javascript#examples)  to do that.

I POST to : `SERVICE_URL/v3/conversations/`

BODY:

```
{
  "bot": {
    "id": BOT_ID
  },
  "members": [
    {
      "id": USER_ID
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": TENANT_ID
    }
  }
}
```

BOT_ID - I put the app id of the bot (with a prefix of "28:")

USERֹ_ID - I copied the USER_ID from a message I received from the user (not in a proactive message)

TENANT_ID - I took the tenant id from the link of the teams

I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadSyntax",
        "message": "Invalid user identity in provided tenant"
    }
}
```

I made several attempts to change the user ID: I changed to a user that appears in ADD, I changed with a prefix of 29: and without a prefix of 29: - nothing helped, this error continues to appear.

What am I missing?

Comment: USERֹ_ID - I copied the USER_ID from a message I received from the user (not in a proactive message) - message mean when user interacted with bot?. Could you please try one of these methods as mentioned in this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#obtain-necessary-user-information) to fetch the user information? try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT. Yes, I took the information when user interacted with bot.

Comment: Could you please fetch the  user information using  [fetching the team roster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#fetching-the-roster-or-user-profile)? Use the tenant id and user id which you got from fetch roster. Try if that helps.