# Error "Invalid user identity in provided tenant" when creating a new conversation for the bot on ms teams

Tags: rest, botframework

I am building a chatbot on microsoft teams using REST, it worked fine when responding to user messages, however I am having problems creating conversations with new users, I experimented with postman and followed the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

This is my post data:

- Post URL: https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/v3/conversations
- Header:
  [image]
- Body:

```
    "bot": {
        "id": "..........",
        "name": "ChatBot"
    },
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": ".........."
        }
    ],
    "channelData": {
        "tenant": {
            "id": "..........."
        }
    }
}
```

I got the "Invalid user identity in provided tenant" error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadSyntax",
        "message": "Invalid user identity in provided tenant"
    }
}
```

I checked the id values ​​entered but didn't find any errors, "bot id" is the Microsoft App ID that can be seen on the azure portal, the "member" id I got from the profile on graph explorer, "tenant Id" from url link team. Someone please help me, thanks you very much.

Comment: refer to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/getting-quot-badsyntax-invalid-user-identity-in-provided-tenant/m-p/1347613 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929651/teams-botframework-send-proactive-message-rest-api

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem, but I don't see the solution here.